# Modify gradle's runtime dependencies according to operation system?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Is it possible to change gradle's runtime dependencies according to the what the operation system it is on?

I'm using the SWT in my application which has jars that are platform dependent. I want to only distribute the right SWT jar for each platform it is running. Something like:

```
dependencies {
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'swt', include: 'swt_win_32.jar') if windows.
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'swt', include: 'swt_linux_x86.jar') if linux.
}
```

Hope this question make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String jarName;
switch(System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().split()[0]) {
  case 'windows':
    jarName = 'swt_win_32.jar' 
    break
  case 'linux':
    jarName = 'swt_linux_x86.jar' 
    break
  default:
    throw new Exception('Unknown OS')
}

dependencies {
  runtime fileTree(dir: 'swt', include: jarName)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Gradle has no public API to check for OS, but you can use something like System.getProperty("os.name") and act accordingly (e.g with a simple if-statement).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with a more Gradle-ish way to do it you can use 
the Gradle OS Plugin.
https://bitbucket.org/tinhtruong/gradle-os-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The [goomph](https://github.com/diffplug/goomph) plugin has a [mavencentral](https://diffplug.github.io/goomph/javadoc/3.14.0/com/diffplug/gradle/eclipse/MavenCentralPlugin.html) plugin specifically for this purpose.

```
apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.gradle.eclipse.mavencentral'
eclipseMavenCentral {
  release '4.7.0', {
    compile 'org.eclipse.swt'
    useNativesForRunningPlatform()
  }
}
```