# Use separate dependency as per the platform

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies

I have to include different dependencies according to the platform, for instance windows and linux using gradle/maven.

How can I make sure I only use the dependency needed for windows while building windows jar and linux while creating linux jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Maven pom.xml

For Example,

- SWT for Windows and Linux is different.
- and when I use `jpackage`, On Windows, icon file is `ico`, On Linux, icon file is `png`

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${swt.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${swt.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${swt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

and Add profile

```
    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>Linux</name>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <swt.groupId>org.eclipse.platform</swt.groupId>
                <swt.artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</swt.artifactId>
                <swt.version>3.119.0</swt.version>
                <zname>linux_x86_64</zname>
                <iconType>png</iconType>
                <zformat>tar.gz</zformat>
            </properties>
        </profile>


<profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>Windows 10</name>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <swt.groupId>org.eclipse.platform</swt.groupId>
                <swt.artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</swt.artifactId>
                <swt.version>3.119.0</swt.version>
                <zname>windows_x86_64</zname>
                <iconType>ico</iconType>
                <zformat>zip</zformat>
            </properties>
        </profile>
...
```

## How to know your activation os name and arch value ?

Run `mvn help:system | grep "os\."`  on Linux

get result:

```
os.name=Linux os.version=5.13.0-40-generic os.arch=amd64
```

Run `mvn help:system | findstr "os\."`  on Windows

get result:

```
os.name=Windows 10 os.version=10.0 os.arch=amd64
```

Mapping os name and os arch into `profile` -> `activation` -> `os` -> `name`
and `os` -> `arch`, then config `profile` -> `properties` Set the corresponding value into   `swt.groupId`,`swt.artifactId`,`swt.version`.

When you run `mvn clean package` , maven will auto select profile activation by mapping to os.name and os.arch value.

Comment: Thank you so much @life888888 but I am trying to achieve the same using gradle.

Comment: very old answer: `Modify gradle's runtime dependencies according to operation system?`( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796615/modify-gradles-runtime-dependencies-according-to-operation-system)